# Elastic Stack Help: Logstash Filtering & geoip

Tags: json, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I've been trying to figure this out myself for awhile now, and I'm having difficulty figuring out the syntax for using the logstash filter. In my program I log the user's IP address and other values into keyvalue pairs for json format.

I have a standard setup for the elastic stack that follows:
.net program -> log.json -> filebeat -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana

logstash.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
        json {
         source => "message"
        }
        geoip {
         source => "Portal-IPAddress"
        }
        mutate {
        remove_field => ["Timestamp","message","MessageTemplate","log.offset","@version"]
        }
}
   
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

My questions being how can I:

1.Get all key value pairs from "Properties" into their own respective fields

2.Use the Portal-IPAddress field to lookup & set a geoip field (currently lookup fails, even when placing a known working value into that field & I suspect that I'm not locating the proper value with source).

for extra info here is my log structure

```
{"Timestamp":"2022-11-01T16:36:24.4924785-07:00","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"\"Portal-Module\":\"{Portal-Module}\",\"Portal-SubModule\":\"{Portal-SubModule}\",\"Portal-Action\":\"{Portal-Action}\",\"Portal-Result\":\"{Portal-Result}\",\"Portal-User\":\"{Portal-User}\",\"Portal-Object\":\"{Portal-Object}\",\"Portal-Message\":\"{Portal-Message}\",\"Portal-URL\":\"{Portal-URL}\",\"Portal-Milliseconds\":{Portal-Milliseconds},\"Portal-IPAddress\":\"{Portal-IPAddress}\",\"Portal-LogType\":\"{Portal-LogType}\",","Properties":{"Portal-Module":"Reporting","Portal-SubModule":"Availability","Portal-Action":"Generate","Portal-Result":"Succeeded","Portal-User":"local","Portal-Object":"Run on Large Screen","Portal-Message":"","Portal-URL":"https://localhost:5001/reports/availability?readydate=20230630&seasonids=112&pricelevelid=37","Portal-Milliseconds":5636,"Portal-IPAddress":"::1","Portal-LogType":"FrontEnd","SourceContext":"Portal.Web.Services.PortalLogger","TransportConnectionId":"caBKjkS1R-Rzkz4auPIAcA","RequestId":"0HMLSB0UJLBU9:00000002","RequestPath":"/_blazor","ConnectionId":"0HMLSB0UJLBU9","MachineName":"WS-56","ClientIp":"::1","ClientAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/91.0.4516.95","Email":"local","IsImpersonating":false,"Environment":"Development"}}
```

logstash output

```
{
    "Properties" => {
                "SourceContext" => "Portal.Web.Services.PortalLogger",
                  "RequestPath" => "/_blazor",
                  "MachineName" => "WS-56",
                   "Portal-URL" => "https://localhost:5001/reports/availability?readydate=20230630&seasonids=112&pricelevelid=37",
                        "Email" => "local",
                "Portal-Result" => "Succeeded",
                 "ConnectionId" => "0HMLSB0UJLBU9",
                "Portal-Object" => "Run on Large Screen",
          "Portal-Milliseconds" => 5636,
        "TransportConnectionId" => "caBKjkS1R-Rzkz4auPIAcA",
                  "Environment" => "Development",
                    "RequestId" => "0HMLSB0UJLBU9:00000002",
               "Portal-LogType" => "FrontEnd",
             "Portal-SubModule" => "Availability",
               "Portal-Message" => "",
             "Portal-IPAddress" => "x",
                     "ClientIp" => "x",
              "IsImpersonating" => false,
                  "ClientAgent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/91.0.4516.95",
                "Portal-Action" => "Generate",
                "Portal-Module" => "Reporting",
                  "Portal-User" => "local"
    },
          "host" => {
            "hostname" => "WS-56",
                  "os" => {
               "build" => "19044.2130",
                "name" => "Windows 10 Pro",
            "platform" => "windows",
                "type" => "windows",
              "family" => "windows",
             "version" => "10.0",
              "kernel" => "10.0.19041.2130 (WinBuild.160101.0800)"
        },
                "name" => "WS-56",
                  "ip" => [
            [0] "x",
            [1] "x",
            [2] "x",
            [3] "x",
            [4] "x",
            [5] "x",
            [6] "x"
        ],
                 "mac" => [
            [0] "x",
            [1] "x"
        ],
        "architecture" => "x86_64",
                  "id" => "72eeb3df-a50c-4be6-8c13-ca7a860e61e0"
    },
         "agent" => {
            "hostname" => "WS-56",
                "name" => "WS-56",
                "type" => "filebeat",
        "ephemeral_id" => "ed62668d-e91c-47e0-9b41-dd0854f13c06",
             "version" => "7.14.1",
                  "id" => "c8494d5f-c460-4977-849e-c61c4fd1726f"
    },
           "log" => {
        "offset" => 89193,
          "file" => {
            "path" => "C:\\ProgramData\\filebeat\\datalogs\\log-11-2022-20221101.json"
        }
    },
         "input" => {
        "type" => "log"
    },
          "tags" => [
        [0] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ],
    "@timestamp" => 2022-11-01T23:36:33.462Z,
         "Level" => "Information",
           "ecs" => {
        "version" => "1.10.0"
    }
}
```

Every sensitive value has been replaced with "x", but ip & mac addresses are generating properly

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to answer my own question by editing how my logger outputs the json file.

By creating a custom json formatter for use in the rolling file Serilog sink, I was able format all properties into individual fields instead of nesting all of them in the "Properties" field that the default Json formatter used.
[image]